# Lost and mostly drowned

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

*Don't go diving looking for those, you won't find much*

> Cardigan Bay [5]
> Atlantic [3]
> Baie de Douarnenez [1]
> Baltic Sea [4]
> Lake Svetloyar [6]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [**R'lyeh**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%27lyeh)

I found this answer by

> Theorizing, based on the title, that we might be looking for *lost cities*, specifically *sunken cities,* which are former cities that, according to myths, are now at the location of a currently-existing body of water.

Indeed,

> [**Cantre'r Gwaelod**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantre%27r_Gwaelod) is supposedly a lost city located in modern-day Cardigan Bay.
>  **Atlantis** is in the Atlantic.
>  [**Ys**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ys) is in Baie de Douarnenez.
>  [**Vineta**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vineta) is in the Baltic Sea.
>  And [**Kitezh**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitezh) is in Lake Svetloyar.

And finally

> Given the number n, we take the nth letter of the respective sunken city. This gives us Cant(R)e'r Gwaelod + At(L)antis + (Y)s + Vin(E)ta + Kitez(H) -> RLYEH -> R'lyeh.

The answer is apt since

> R'lyeh itself is a fictional lost city in H.P. Lovecraft's short story, "The Call of Cthulhu", where it is located in the southern Pacific Ocean. (More details about the city in the link in the first spoiler.)

Comment: Seasonal, too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rflsHvtTTGw :-)